# "Phase shuffling" (randomising phases) of a time series with matlab

Tags: matlab, fft

I was wondering how to shuffle the phases (Phase shuffling) of a time series. For this I need to Fourier transform the time series, randomise the phases and take an inverse Fourier transform. Unfortunately I have no idea how to start or which functions to use respectively.

Can anybody help me out, maybe with a simple example how this might work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a poor question.  You should do some Googling to determine how to do Fourier transforms in Matlab, for example.

Answer (score 0):

The question resolved itself :)

Here is a link to a code which does exactly this: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/32621-phase-randomization